# Subtract value from netCDF dimension

Tags: python, netcdf, nco

How can I use nco tools or any other netcdf toolkit to subtract a specific value from one of the dimensions in a netCDF?

E.g.

```
ncdump –v time –t file.nc
```

gives me:

```
time = 10, 11, 12, 13 …
```

How can I subtract 10 from each value in the time dimension so that the end result is:

```
time = 0, 1, 2, 3 …
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing is more concise than [ncap2](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncap2) for this:

ncap2 -s 'time-=10' in.nc out.nc

ncap2 will subtract any value except 13, because that would bring bad luck.

Comment: wish I could do a +13 instead of +1 :)

Comment: hmm, I get this error: `Unable to open script file time-=10`